# Loading an javascript image object from a server file

Tags: javascript, image

I am developing a mobile application that has this scenario:  A user goes to one screen where they supply indexing meta data for an image.  From this first screen they can go to a second screen where they select and upload the actual image to go with the meta data.  Once selected, they go back to the first screen where they can then upload both the image and the meta data to a separate web service.  Now, once the image has been selected and the user is back on the first screen, they may want to look at or change the image (that they previously selected) before actually submitting it to the web service.  So I need to provide a way for the user to go back to the second screen and see the image they previously uploaded (without having to select it again).  Clear so far?

In my ASP.Net MVC mobile application code I am caching the uploaded image to the server in a temporary file path on the server.  Now I want to take that saved file and load it into a javascript image object so it can be displayed to the user when they go back to the second screen.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload it to the server, the server can respond with a URL that can be used to retrieve the uploaded image. Capture that response and use it to set the `src` attribute of a new client-side `Image` object.

Comment: You helped me solve it.  The problem was that I was supplying the path to the file in the wrong format.  Thanks for you help.